# Correctly looping through a data set, and displaying, or outputting all results, WITHOUT using a Temporary Table

Tags: plsql

I have some PL/SQL code that is *intended* to loop through the entire month range for each month in each year, and then retrieve the number of times *something* occurred within a monthly period.

Right now, I'm not doing a nested loop for each year that exists because I need to properly understand how this works before continuing.

Here's my code:

```
BEGIN
   FOR i IN 1..11 LOOP
        BEGIN
            SELECT COUNT(UNIQUE EMPLOYEE) as Emp FROM (SELECT DATE_COL, EMPLOYEE
                FROM CORE.DATE_TEST 
            WHERE DATE_COL  >= TO_DATE(i || '/1/2015 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
                AND DATE_COL  < TO_DATE((i + 1) || '/1/2015 23:59:59', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
            ORDER BY DATE_COL ASC);
        END;
   END LOOP;
   COMMIT;
END;
```

And I'm getting this error: `PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement`

Obviously, I need to select the results into *something*, but what that something is, I'm not quite sure. This may not even be the right way to do it.

However, I'd like to take all of these results, and combine them into a single table like this:

```
+----------+-------+
|   date   | count |
+----------+-------+
| January  |  200  |
+----------+-------|
| February |  100  |
+----------+-------|
| March    |  500  |
+----------+-------|
```

And so on.

**EDIT**: There are no priviledges to create a `TABLE`, or even a `GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE`. This needs to be done without temporary tables.

Comment: This could just be implemented as a single SQL statement, to get the employee count for every month and year.

Comment: Could you give me an example, please?

Comment: You would create a query that generates a list of months (plenty of examples should be Googleable, many of them on StackOverflow), and join that to the CORE.DATE_TEST table using the same join method as in your example query.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, David. I've been trying it since you suggested it, but have been unable to get it working. Could you give me an example, please?

Comment: Can you modify your question to show what you've tried?

Answer (score 0):

This will print your query.

```
DECLARE 
    V_number varchar2(100);
    BEGIN
       FOR i IN 1..11 LOOP

                    SELECT COUNT(UNIQUE EMPLOYEE) AS EMP INTO V_number FROM (SELECT CURRENT_DATE, EMPLOYEE
                            FROM CORE.DATE_TEST 
                    WHERE CURRENT_DATE  >= TO_DATE(i || '/1/2015 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
                            AND CURRENT_DATE  < TO_DATE((i + 1) || '/1/2015 23:59:59', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
                    ORDER BY CURRENT_DATE ASC);

                    dbms_output.put_line(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(I || '/1/2015 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'Month')||'  '||V_NUMBER);      
       END LOOP;
    END;
```

Comment: For `TEST_TABLE`: `PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist`. Unsure as to how I should create a Temp Table. Apparently these aren't used often in Oracle.

Comment: Create a normal table like this `CREATE TABLE TEST_TABLE
(
YOUR_MONTH VARCHAR2(100),
EMP NUMBER
);`

Comment: That doesn't work either. The last part, `END;` throws this error: `ORA-00911: invalid character`. I am putting it before the DECLARE statement, though.  Could you please edit your answer with the way it should look?

Comment: You have to execute them separately. I've edited my answer.

Comment: `ORA-01031: insufficient privileges`. I need to do this without using a temp table, it seems.